# If you have an scenario / test for a piece of functionality, do you have to test the opposite?

Tags: testing, specflow, acceptance-testing

I have some acceptance tests that are written in the Gherkin syntax and am automating them using SpecFlow.  One example of a scenario (although it is not in gherkin) is,

"when a review is submitted with a salary increase percentage is above the company threshold, then a "Salary Increase Approver" needs to approve the review."

As you can see, this is an example of a special condition that causes an additional person to have to approve a review.  Given this example, is it necessary to have a scenario for,

"when a review is submitted with a salary increase percentage that is within the company threshold, then the "Salary Increase Approver" does not need to approve the review."

If so, where is the cut off line.  Obviously this could lead to having 2 scenarios for every 1 scenario -- one that pertains to what it is you are trying to accomplish and one that is just verifying that you didn't make a mistake (e.g. the increase approver ends up having to approve every review)

Answer (score 1):

The degree of testing is dependent on various factors including the time you have and the necessity to get it right so this should be considered before deciding to test blindly.

The scenarios you have specified define two very apparent paths through the code and 2 different results so they both should generally be tested.

Ideally you would have an existing suite of tests which should test the existing functionality, in this case it might be a salary increase inside the threshold not requiring the 'salary increase approver' in which case you could recycle this test (run as a regression test) and you would only require a test for increases above the threshold. As you build up your suite of regression tests this testing becomes quicker.

Note: I am not familiar with tools you are using so can't give a related example

Answer (score 1):

```
 > .. do you have to test the opposite?
```

**Until there is a business requirement** i would say **no** because there might also be a scenario that does not require the approver-workflow if employee is a manager or the son of the boss. In this case the simple-threshhold-opposite-test would fail without having any **businessvalue**.

Comment: I guess it comes down to semantics but I believe this statement "when a review is submitted with a salary increase percentage is above the company threshold, then a "Salary Increase Approver" needs to approve the review." "As you can see, this is an example of a special condition" infers a business requirement for being below the threshold and not flagging. Definitely a question for the business analyst though